# AngularJS and order of function checking authenticated user ( Facebook API )

Tags: facebook, angularjs, facebook-javascript-sdk

My code is mostly taken from web, but I wan't to redirect logged in users after they log in and redirect not logged in users to the login page. I've been trying with `resolve` but service method which is checking if user is authorized always shows that he is not ( in resolve ) and then when page is loaded user is being authenticated. I'm bootstraping my app, so I thought I will be getting info from Facebook first, and then app will be loaded.

**index.php** ( script part )

```
<script>
       window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
         FB.init({
           appId      : '191392907718296', 
           channelUrl : '//'+window.location.hostname+'/channel.html', 
           status     : true, 
           cookie     : true, 
           xfbml      : false 
          });

         angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp','ngRoute']);
       };

       (function(d){
          var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
          if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
          js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
          js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
          ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
        }(document));
    </script>
```

**my app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute']);

app.config( function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.

        when('/login', {

        controller : 'MainCtrl',
        templateUrl : 'views/first.html',
        }).
        when('/', {

        controller : 'SecondCtrl',
        templateUrl : 'views/second.html',

        resolve : {
            checkUser : function($location,FBUser)
            {
                console.log(FBUser.authorized);
                $location.path('/login');
            }
        }
        });
    });

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'FBUser',function($scope, FBUser) {
  $scope.user = FBUser;
}]);

app.controller('SecondCtrl', ['$scope',function($scope) {

}]);


app.service('facebook', ['$rootScope', '$window', function ($rootScope, $window) {

  this.askFacebookForAuthentication = function (fail, success) {
    FB.login(function (response) {
      $rootScope.$apply(function () {
        if (response.authResponse) {
          FB.api('/me', success);
        } else {
          fail('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
        }
      });
    });
  };

  this.getLoginStatus = function () {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
      return response;
    });
  };

  this.FB = $window.FB;

}]);

/* --------------- FB API MODELS ------------------ */
app.service('FBUser', ['$log', '$rootScope', 'facebook', function ($log, $rootScope, facebook,$location) {
  var that = this;
  this.authorized = false;

  facebook.FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function (response) {
    $log.info("Event: auth.authResponseChange");

    if (response.authResponse) {
      if (response.status === 'connected') {
        // User logged in and authorized
        $log.info('User logged in and authorized');
        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
          that.authorized = true;
        });

        $rootScope.$apply( function() {
            redirectTo('/'); 
        });

      } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        // User logged in but has not authorized app
        $log.info('User logged in');
        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
          that.authorized = false;
        });
      } else {
        // User logged out
        $log.info('User logged out');
        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
          that.authorized = false;
        });
      }
    } else {
      $log.info('No valid authResponse found, user logged out');
      $rootScope.$apply(function () {
        that.authorized = false;
      });
    }
  });

  this.login = function (success, fail) {
    facebook.FB.login(function (response) {
      $rootScope.$apply(function () {
        if (response.authResponse) {
          success(response);
        } else {
          fail('Login unsuccessful');
        }
      });
    });
  };

  this.logout = function () {
    facebook.FB.logout(function () {
      $rootScope.$apply(function () {
        that.authorized = false;
      });
    });
  };
}]);
```